# Non increasing and Non Decreasing Subsequence

Tags: string, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

Finding non-decreasing subsequence is well known problem.
But this Question is a slight variant of the finding longest non-decreasing subsequence. In this problem we have to find the **length** of longest subsequence which comprises 2 disjoint sequences 1. non decreasing 2. non-increasing.
e.g. in string "aabcazcczba" longest such sequence is aabczcczba. aabczcczba is made up of 2 disjoint subsequence aabcZccZBA. (capital letter shows non-increasing sequence)

My algorithm is

```
length = 0
For i = 0 to length of given string S
  let s' = find the longest non-decreasing subsequence starting at position i
  let s" = find the longest non-increasing subsequence from S-s'.
  if (length of s' + length of s") > length
      length = (length of s' + length of s")
enter code here
```

But I am not sure whether this would give correct answer or not. Can you find a bug in this algo and if there is bug also suggest correct algorithm. Also I need to optimize the solution. My algorithm would take roughly o(n^4) steps.

Comment: aabczcczba is made of 3 fragments aabcz is non-increasing and zba is non-decreasing.  but what is the cc between those? how does that work?  if you can have anything in the middle, then take your first and last letters as the two sequences and include everything else.

Comment: What do you mean by "subsequence", a continuous interval or just a sequence made up of some of the original elements in the same order?

Comment: subsequence is made from removing any number of characters (can also be 0) from the original string. e.g, aac is subsequence of aabc

Comment: @andrewcooke aabcz is non decreasing subsequence not non increasing. And, you elaborate little more

Comment: sorry, swap increase/decrease.  point remains: what is "cc" in teh middle doing?  how is that part of anything?

Comment: @andrewcooke cc is paart of original sequence so it could occur in the subsequence. If you could notice aabcZccZBA can be broken down into 2 disjoint sequences aabccc (non-decreasing) and this aabcZccZBA subsequence is the longest subsequence we can get from original sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is definitely incorrect. Eg. addddbc. The longest non-decreasing sequence is adddd, but that would never give you a non-increasing sequence. The optimal solution is abc and dddd ( or ab ddddc, or ac ddddb).

One solution is to use dynamic programming.

F(i, x, a, b) = 1, if there is a non-decreasing and non-increasing combo from first i letters of x ( x[:i]) such that last letter of non-decreasing part is a, and non-increasing part is b. Both of these letters equal to NULL if the corresponding sub-sequence is empty.

Otherwise F(i, x, a, b) = 0.

```
F(i+1,x,x[i+1],b) = 1 if there exists a and b such that 
    a<=x[i+1] or a=NULL and F(i,x,a,b)=1. 0 otherwise.

F(i+1,x,a,x[i+1]) = 1 if there exists a and b such that
    b>=x[i+1] or b=NULL and F(i,x,a,b)=1. 0 otherwise. 

Initialize F(0,x,NULL,NULL)=1 and iterate from i=1..n
```

As you can see, you can get F(i+1, x, a, b) from F(i, x, a, b). Complexity: Linear in length, polynomial in size of the alphabet.

Comment: I got that my approach is wrong and will not give right solution. But can you explain how will this help in finding length of the longest subsequence?

Comment: @Amey For a given sequence of length n it is easy to see that this algorithm finds the longest subsequence that satisfy your criteria. Now, move the start point along and you can find the global optimal. Complexity O(n^2).

Comment: its still not clear to me. The sub-sequence need not have continuous characters from original string. Does your solution include such sub sequence? Can you explain with the given example. Let the string be x=addddbc. 

We will have F(0,x,NULL,NULL) = 1 then F(1,x,'a',NULL) = 1 and another possibility will be F(1,x,NULL,'a') = 1. So will this solution have space complexity = o(n^3) right?

Comment: what i understood from your solution is - to maintain a table of (n*n) where entry in table[i][j] denotes length of sub sequence which has non-increasing sub sequence whose last character is x[i] and has non-decreasing sub sequence whose last character is x[j]. Is is similar to what you meant?

But i guess the problem is if some character a, s.t. a >= x[j] and a <= x[i] then to which sub sequence should a belong? decreasing or increasing?

Comment: You need a table that is of dimension n*k*k where k is the size of your alphabet (eg. If alphabet is a-z, then k=26).

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, And here is how it works, thanx to @ElKamina

maintain a table of 27X27 dimension. 27 = (1 Null character + 26 (alphabets))
table[i][j] denotes the length of the sub sequence whose non decreasing subsequence has last character 'i' and non increasing subsequence has last character 'j' (0th index denote null character and kth index denotes character 'k')

for i = 0 to length of string S

```
  //subsequence whose non decreasing subsequence's last character is smaller than S[i], find such a subsequence of maximum length. Now S[i] can be part of this subsequence's non-decreasing part.

  int lim = S[i] - 'a' + 1;
  for(int k=0; k<27; k++){
    if(lim == k) continue;
    int tmax = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<=lim; j++){
      if(table[k][j] > tmax) tmax = table[k][j];
    }
    if(k == 0 && tmax == 0) table[0][lim] = 1;
    else if (tmax != 0) table[k][lim] = tmax + 1;
  }
 //Simillarly for non-increasing subsequence
```

Time complexity is o(lengthOf(S)*27*27) and space complexity is o(27*27)